# Why is my bands showing black after atmospheric correction using SCP plugin(DOS1) in QGIS or DOS in Erdas?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, digital-image-processing, image-classification

I am classifying Landsat TM and Landsat ETM (level 1) scenes for my study area as part of my research(LU/LC). The scenes are in a single tile and span 5 different timelines. I have done the radiometric processing (radiance, TOA and sun corrected TOA).

However, it is showing the bands as a black background. I am not able to figure out how the fix the issue.

[image: image sun corrected TOA]

[image: Post atmospheric correction]

Comment: Let's go a step further, have you tried the image classification with or without atmospheric correction? were there any differences?

Comment: Hi, I tried to do the atmospheric correction, because my supervisor wanted me to do it. But there has been some issues. My bands are showing a black background